# How do I run all tests in a specific folder in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I have a number of tests in a particular folder which I would like to run.

If I right click on that folder, I would expect a "run.." option, to be able to run these tests. I faintly remember from past releases of WebStorm that it was possible to do this.

How can I run a group of test files in WebStorm?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-41505](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41505) to be notified on any progress with it

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a new Run Task, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/performing-tests.html) you have a link for more info about how to perform tests in WebStorm, about this particular case, you could do the following (In this example, the test tool used is Jest, but this same step applies to all the tools supported by Webstorm):

1. On the main toolbar select `Run` and them `Run...` (Or just press `Shift+Alt+F10`).
2. Select `Edit configurations...` in order to create a new Run Task.

[image]

3. And here you have to fill all the details, pay particular attention to `Working directory` because in that field you are going to define in which folder do you want the Task to run, also, at the end you could select if you want to run only test files or all the test found in the folder.

Hope this helps.